# If $a,b,c ∈ \mathbb R^+$ prove $(\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{1}{2})(\frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{1}{2})(\frac{c}{a+b} + \frac{1}{2}) \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$a,b,c ∈ \mathbb R^+$
$$(\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{1}{2})(\frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{1}{2})(\frac{c}{a+b} + \frac{1}{2}) \ge 1$$

For this one I have little to no idea how to solve it. I tried some *AM-GM* and also some other manipulations but didn't give me anything that would equal or sum to 1. Tittu Lemma seems like a good option to solve this one , but using $\sqrt{a}$ in order to apply it , still doesn't give any good result. Or I am probably giving up too early.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1703668p10955785

Comment: Another one on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2199449p16554145

Answer (score 4):

Because by AM-GM  $$\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\prod_{cyc}\frac{a+b+a+c}{b+c}\geq\frac{1}{8}\prod_{cyc}\frac{2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}{b+c}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution
[image]

I hope my writing won't be an issue

Comment: Please don't post pictures as solutions. Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks I will take care from now on